# Adding custom transition to tabstrip in openui5

Tags: sapui5

Can the navigation between [tabs](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#test-resources/sap/ui/commons/demokit/TabStrip.html) be customized to as in the [navcontainer](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.NavContainer/preview) i.e. while selecting tabs the view should scroll and change from left to right like swipe navigation with new page as in navcontainer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve the slide in effect rather easily by adding the following CSS to your application

```
@keyframes slidein {
  from { 
    right: -100%; 
  }
  to {  
    right: -6px; 
  }
}
.sapUiTabPanel {
  overflow:hidden;  
}
.sapUiTabPanel > * { 
  animation: slidein 500ms; 
  position: absolute;  
}
```

Note that you may need to add CSS with vendor prefixes depending on which browsers you are supporting.

To achieve the slide out of the current displayed tab is a bit tricky, one possible way this could be achieved is with the following code added to somewhere like the onInit method of your controller

```
oTabStrip1.attachBrowserEvent("mousedown",function(oEvent){
  var oTarget = oEvent.target;
  if(oTarget.className==="sapUiTabClose"){
    return;
  }
  var iIdx = oTabStrip1.getItemIndex(oTarget);
  if (iIdx > -1) {
    if ((iIdx !== oTabStrip1.getSelectedIndex()) && (oTabStrip1.getTabs()[iIdx].getEnabled())) {
      oEvent.stopPropagation();
      oEvent.preventDefault();
      jQuery.each(
      oTabStrip1.getTabs()[oTabStrip1.getSelectedIndex()].getContent(),function(i,o){
        var sAnimateLeft = (o.$().innerWidth() * -1) + "px";
        o.$().animate({left:sAnimateLeft},500);
      });
      setTimeout(function(){
        oTabStrip1.selectTabByDomRef(oTarget);
      },250);

    }
  }
});
```

The above is assuming oTabStrip1 is the instance of your tabstrip control. Although it's often not good practice to modify the DOM directly within UI5 applications, in this case it's probably safe as the content of the displayed tab is removed and replaced with the clicked tab content, so all we are doing is delaying this until the slide out animation is complete.

You can see a working example at http://jsbin.com/vukibi - the code has been taken directly from the [tabstrip example](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#test-resources/sap/ui/commons/demokit/TabStrip.html) with the above CSS and JS added

Comment: Thanks . However when I try [this](http://jsbin.com/kizonezadu/edit?js,output) it do not work as expected can you tell why. I added a tabstrip to a tab and added style class to that particular tabstrip but it does not work.

Comment: The CSS might require tweaking depending on the controls you have within your tab strip, for the example you've provided you can add the following styling:

.dasboardTab {
  position:relative;
}

Comment: sorry I sent the wrong bin. Here is the [bin](http://jsbin.com/teyewuzeqe/1/edit?css,js,output) here it works fine . But when implementing the same code in my application there is a tiny glitch i.e. when the parent tab is loaded for the 1st time the slide animation occurs twice and then after works normal with or without `event handler for mousedown`.

Comment: It's difficult to say without seeing your code, but chances are your controls are initially being rendered twice if the slide in effect is happening 2 times. The event handler for mousedown is to handle the slide out effect of the current displayed tab, without this only the slide in effect will work.